# Prolog- Loading A Library from a File

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

The Sicstus manual says to use this to load a library:
use_module(library(Package)).
This works in Prolog on the command line, but I can't find out how to load a library from a Prolog source file. When I include "use_module(library(Package))." in my .pl file, I get a permission error: cannot redefine built_in use_module/1.

Comment: If anyone drops by, I have prepared this little example set: [Prolog module loading example: Loading the "lynx" library](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/loading_lynx_library.md)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a *directive*, such as:

```
:- use_module(library(Package)).
```

...at the top of your file, where `Package` is the atom identifying the library module you want to load.